# Docker remove old images after container is done running

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that gets built into image programatrically. Each time the image has been built, I will run the container with the `--rm` tag to auto delete the container ([image: container empty])
It is working as expected. However I realize after the container has been cleaned up, there is a list of images still around. Each time I build a new image and run the container, it shows all the images "IN USE".

[image: list of images]

I also tried running the image build command with `--rm` but it doesn't work.
If I were to remove the image right after building, then I won't be able to run the container?
I should run the container first, delete it, then remove the image, right?

How can I do this using the tag/option like rm?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such key as `--rm` for images, but you can do with something like this:

```
docker build -t tmp . && docker run --rm -it tmp; docker image rm tmp
```

There is also `docker image prune` which can delete unused images in bulk.